# How can I create Windows software on Ubuntu?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++, windows-8, ubuntu-16.04

Can I use Visual Studio on Ubuntu?
How can I use Anjuta for windows software development using c++ language?

Comment: Do you only want to create console (or text) only programs? Or programs using the native Windows API? What are your requirements?

Comment: I am beginner. I just want to create a console software.basically I want to change .CPP into .exe file

Comment: Oh, and the answer to your question is "no". The answer to your question in the *title* on the other hand is "yes". In short, you can write programs for Windows all in Linux, but you can't use Visual Studio (directly, is possible through a virtual machine installation of Windows though).

Comment: If you're not creating programs using anything of the Windows API, only standard C++, then do some research about *cross-compilation*. And probably about [MinGW](http://www.mingw.org/) as well.

Comment: okk..but Is there any other option to create windows software on Ubuntu?